# Origine dell'espressione "tagliare il vestito addosso a qualcuno"

Tags: idioms, etymology

Leggendo ***Il corso delle cose***, il primo romanzo di Andrea Camilleri, ho letto questa frase:

> "Nell'anticamera dovette attardarsi perché la porta d'ingresso faceva
>   resistenza ad aprirsi e intese Vasalicò esclamare a voce alta un - eh,
>   povero Vito! - che era un invito alla sparla, a *tagliargli il vestito
>   addosso*."

Ho trovato che "tagliare il vestito addosso a qualcuno" significa criticare, parlar male, sparlarne alle spalle di qualcuno. Mi domando, però, da dove provenga questa curiosa espressione.

Comment: Nota anche che "_sparla_" non è un sostantivo registrato dai dizionari :-) Si tratta probabilmente di parola dialettale siciliana, ma il suo significato è chiarissimo :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'espressione *tagliare il vestito addosso* proviene dal mondo della sartoria, ed è un'analogia tra le seguenti immagini:

- Il sarto che prende le misure delle diverse parti del corpo, confeziona una prima versione del vestito e lo prova sul cliente, per poi rimuoverne le imperfezioni, sistemarlo e consegnare a questi il prodotto finito.
- La persona che mette in evidenza particolari, difetti, azioni di altre persone per poi iniziare un discorso di critica nei loro confronti.

In entrambe le situazioni l'azione è quella di ricerca di particolari, finezze, errori; tuttavia, il sarto lo fa per migliorare il proprio lavoro, chi critica lo fa per aver più punti di appoggio nel proprio discorso.

Non ho trovato fonti di primo livello, ma solo [questo articolo](http://www.oggi7.info/2007/11/14/462-il-linguaio-tagliare-alzare-i-panni-ed-i-tacchi) e [questo post](http://faustoraso.blogspot.it/2012/08/tagliare-i-panni-addosso-qualcuno.html).

---

Nella seguente [pagina](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/P/panno.shtml), viene fornita un'interpretazione dell'espressione equivalente a "tagliare, lacerare i vestiti di una persona per metterne a nudo le debolezze ed i difetti" (grazie a @randomatlabuser per la segnalazione).

Comment: +1, la Treccani lo riporta in tre diverse voci, [tagliare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tagliare/), [panno](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/panno/) e [addosso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/addosso/) (_tagliare i panni addosso a uno_). Sul Dizionario del Corriere c'è un'[interpretazione alternativa](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/P/panno.shtml), che però mi sembra un po' bizzarra.